# Assign value to edit field in ASP.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, viewbag

I am from C/C++ background and this simple problem is nightmare for me.

```
ViewBag.description = "description";
```

this viewbag contains stirng "descriptuon"

Here is editbox txtdescription and i want to assign this viewbag data to this textbox.
(it would be awesome if i know that viewbag is contain any data or not)

```
<div>
       @Html.TextBox("txtDescription")
</div>
```

trust html asp is much more challanging than low level programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry to hear that you find web programming little not interesting. You can do following to bind your viewbag data in your textbox

```
@Html.TextBox("txtDescription", (string)ViewBag.Title)
```

As to check if ViewBag is null or not you can do following:

```
@if (ViewBag.Title != null)
{
    //do your textbox assignment here.
}
```

Comment: Thank you Qamar... it worked for me... If you can suggent me few website for these type of tips... would be great...

Comment: please see asp.net blog and also take an online course from plurarlsight. there are plenty of contents on youtube as well

Comment: Not that it matters, but shouldn't it be `ViewBag.description`?

Comment: IMO having anything in viewbag is a bad idea. Every view should evolve around a viewmodel and should be bounded to it to ferry data back and forth. In any case he gets the answer